# Can't start rails server; bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have somehow managed to break my rails, but I can't figure out what to do to fix it. I get this error:

```
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
```

when trying to run both

```
rails s
```

and

```
rails server
```

Now, through some googling it was suggested to run:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

But if I run that, I get this:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/TK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library     not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /Users/TK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/pg-0.17.1/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

I've been trying to fix this for a whole day now, but just can't manage. I've tried using different ruby versions via rvm, reinstalling rvm, reinstalling ruby, reinstalling rails. I'm on OSX Yosemite if that makes a difference.

I'd be super thankful for any suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `APP_PATH` variable initialized twice in your app?

Comment: That first one is a warning, not an error. It still shouldn’t be happening, but if it is it isn’t the cause of your app not running (although of course it could be related). The second one looks like an issue with your insallation of Postgres.

Comment: Yes, matt. I did actually try to migrate from mysql to postgres within my application, and after I've tried that this issue occurred. Do you have an idea what I could do to fix it now?

Comment: Thanks for your help, matt was spot on. I reinstalled postgresql by simply running this `brew uninstall postgresql` and `brew install postgresql`. Now my app is working again.